# Tried to parse HTML String without using Jsoup. Do I have any other options?

Tags: java, parsing

Can I put all HTML tags into one array and loop parsing them from my String? I tried few things around but none are working. Help would be appreciated!! :)
For example:    String str = (Head) 
                 (title)
                    Hello World
                 (/title)
              (/head);

Can I parse everything between Parentheses. i.e. (...sometext...) out of my String?
This is my school project so I'm not allowed to use any other class than basic ones

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as @Jens say in his comment, using regex

```
\((.+?)\)
```

Capture every character between parentheses.

[Running example](https://regex101.com/r/hS6pQ4/2)

Answer (score -2):

You can use htmlunit

HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal" browser.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Comment: As its mentionned in the question "This is my school project so I'm not allowed to use any other class than basic ones"  so he cannot use HtmlUnit

Comment: I do not know if it is already compatible with Android, the last time I researched this library it was not compatible since it used classes and java packages that it does not have in Android.